# scroll to function show #id in url javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using jquery.scrollTo.js to scroll to blocks in one page onclick.

Html Code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#about" class="panel">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#product" class="panel">Products</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="about" class="item">
<a name="about"></a>
About content
</div>
<div id="product" class="item">
<a name="product"></a>
Products content
</div>
```

Internal Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.panel').click(function () {

$('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
current = $(this);
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Please refer http://jsfiddle.net/8up4A/ to just view the code in jquery.scrollTo.js . I am trying to show the id name along with the url like `http://www.test.com/index.html#about`.

If i removed return false in internal script the id displays in url but the scrolling not working correctly. How to achieve this without affecting the scrolling effect. Any Help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to have a live example demo on a site like jsfiddle for us to manipulate?

Comment: you can do it simply by html   <a href="#yourid">test</a> it will scroll to your id  div

Comment: Please verify http://jsfiddle.net/8up4A/8/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.panel').click(function() {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var currentString = $(this).attr('href');
        var newString = currentString.substr(1);

        $("html,body").animate({
             scrollTop: $('a[name="'+newString+'"]').offset().top
         }, 2000);

    });
});
```

And you can remove the scrollTo.js plugin, you don't need it.

Comment: I tried your code. But when i click the link it just jumped to the block not scrolling. Any help?

Comment: Yes. I used Jquery 1.10

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E7vpP/1/
In this example the scroll animation is taking place on the html and body elements, so make sure they exist in your markup. I've tested this in firefox and chrome. Also, if you reproduce this locally you should see the '#name' append to the url.